# PHP, MySQL: Is it possible to cache a subquery?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a page-hit counter. The owner of a page will place on the page a little counter image with a link to my script in a web server; when somebody opens the page in their browser, my script will get invoked and generate an image of the hit number to be sent back to the browser.

From **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** I get the page URL in order to identify the page ID: **$page_id**, and from **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** — viewer's host's IP: **$ip**, since I count only unique IPs. These data are collected in table **Hits(page_id, ip)**.

In order to count the previous hits, I count the number of stored IPs for the given page:

```
$res1 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT ip FROM Hits WHERE page_id='$page_id'");
$number_of_hits = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
```

Now I need to test whether the newly arrived IP is not listed among the old ones, otherwise I would discard it and wouldn't increment the counter. I can either run a loop through the rows already found by the query, or issue another query:

```
$res2 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT ip FROM Hits WHERE page_id='$page_id' AND ip='$ip'");
$number_of_new_hit_occasions = mysqli_num_rows($res2);
if($number_of_new_hit_occasions == 0) ++$number_of_hits;
```

But the second query is essentially redundant and as resource-consuming, as the first one; it would be much more efficient just to search through the small result obtained in the first query, than through the whole table in the second one.

I wish I could store the first query in a virtual table  in the memory named, say, **IPs_for_given_page** (maybe somehow referred in **$res1**), and reduce the second query to

```
$res2 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT ip FROM IPs_for_given_page WHERE ip='$ip'");
$number_of_new_hit_occasions = mysqli_num_rows($res2);
```

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_num_rows to count`, use `COUNT` as @OllieJones says, is much more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to cache results as you mention. But there is a more efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

To count rows, use this kind of query and retrieve the one-row result set. This is much faster than counting rows in a resultset.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hits WHERE page_id=<<whatever>>
```

You can automate the deduplication of ip numbers by doing two things:

First, create a compound unique index on `(page_id,ip)`.

Second, use this SQL statement to insert the hit row.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Hits (page_id, ip) VALUES (<<whatever>>, <<whatever>>)
```

The unique index combined with the `IGNORE` clause together prevent MySQL from accepting duplicate hit rows for the same ip address.

For what it's worth, the compound index I've suggested will also accelerate your COUNT query.

Comment: I appreciate very much your advice, and probably this is the best way to go, but doesn't my question have an affirmative answer:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IPs_for_given_page AS (SELECT ip FROM Hits WHERE page_id='$page_id');` ?